# Why are some tables randomly inheriting this css style?

Tags: html, css, html-table

It seems like some tables are inheriting styles that they shouldn't.

I have a custom table class, and I want only tables that use that class to have a 1px width solid border, but for some reason other tables seem to use it randomly.

Here's the CSS for it:

```
.my_custom_table td, th { border: 1px solid gray; }
```

and here's the markup for a table that uses it for some reason:

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" class="customer-info"> ... </table>
```

I'm thinking the style says "for all td and td under the class .my_custom_table - use 1px solid border", or am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your CSS will apply to **all** `<th>` tags, not just those under the `my_custom_table` class.

Try this instead:

```
.my_custom_table td, .my_custom_table th { border: 1px solid gray; }
```

Comment: really? that doesnt make sense to me :P so does that mean i have to do this?

.my_custom_table p, my_custom_table li, my_custom_table ul
{
    margin: 5px 3px 7px 5px;
}

or does that only apply to table headers 'th'?

Comment: @Jerrold, it makes perfect sense: the selectors in a list of selectors are independent of each other. E.g., `A B, C` has two selectors, `A B` and `C`, and the `C` knows nothing of what’s before it.

Comment: @Jerrold Think about it from another perspective: what if you had another class you also wanted to include in your list of selectors (e.g., `.my_other_custom_table td`)? If the comma was used the way you think, you wouldn't be able to handle that case.

Answer (score 2):

`.my_custom_table td, th` means all the `td` elements in something with a `my_custom_table` class AND all of the `th` elements. Notice that's not all the `th` in something with a `my_custom_table` class. Just all the `th`.

```
.my_custom_table td, .my_custom_table th
```

is what you want.